# Use in form_for field, which is not in object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters, form-for

I have such form:

```
= form_for @order do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :city , "Использовать данные вашего профиля*: "
    = f.radio_button :usercase, true, :required => true
    = f.radio_button :usercase, false, :required => true
  .field
    = f.label :city , "Город*: "
    = f.text_field :city, :placeholder => "Minsk", :required => true
```

But field :usercase is not presented in @order. How could i send radio_button as params to my controller method?
Now i get: undefined method `usercase'
How to send usercase?

Answer (score 3):

In your `Order` model you can add the `usercase=` method to deal witrh the data. Like this.

```
def usercase=(data)
  # DO SOMETHING WITH data
end
```

the variable data will contain the value from the `usercase` field.

// The attr_accessor will define `usercase` and `usercase=` but you whould have to redefine the `usercase=` anyway because you need to do something with the data.

Comment: Validations work only with active record fields so these virtual fields wont work with rails standard validation function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define `usercase` as virtual attribute in `Order` model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :usercase
  ...
end
```

Check [the cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) for more info.

Comment: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: usercase

Comment: Add `:usercase` to `attr_accessible`, `attr_accessible :usercase, ...`

Comment: also, when i try to write   validates :city, :presence => {:message =>  I18n.t(:city_not_chosen)}, :unless => :use_user_data?   i get undefined method `use_user_data?'

Comment: Have you defined `use_user_data?` method? If the attribute (formerly `usercase`) now is `user_user_data`, don't add `?` at the end, `validates ..., unless: :use_user_data`. Also, if you going to add condition to several validations, take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#grouping-conditional-validations